# "hinausstachelnde Bremse" - contradictio in adjecto?

Tags: meaning

In the below sentence (drafted around 1860)

> "Der Begriff des absoluten Systems, nicht als ein Ruhekissen, auch nicht als eine in wüste Irrfahrten **hinausstachelnde Bremse**, sondern als eine ruhige, durch die volle Wirklichkeit sich fortbewegende Entwickelung genommen, enthält so erst die reale Möglichkeit eines wahren bewußt-humanen Verhaltens sowohl gegen die Systeme der Vorzeit, als gegen die verschiedenen gleichzeitigen, mehr oder weniger wissenschaftlichen Ansichten"

I have problems with understanding "**hinausstachelnde Bremse**". "hinausstachelnde Bremse" seems to me to be a "contradictio in adjecto":

I interpret "hinausstachelnde" to have to do with "spurring" (f.i. a horse); i.e. increasing the speed, while "Bremse" (brake) has to do with reducing the speed. But I am probably mistaken?

Comment: https://www.dwds.de/wb/wdg/Bremse

Comment: It would be helpful you added some information about the author of this paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

> while "Bremse" (brake) has to do with reducing the speed. But I am probably mistaken?

Yes, you probably are totally mistaken regarding the translation for *Bremse* as *brake* in that context.

*"hinausstachelnde **Bremse**"* seems to refer to the insect called *gadfly* or *horse fly* in that context.

Comment: While the participle (`hinausstachelnd` [`'stingerstabbing'`]) suggests this reading, it would be a bad metaphor as a gadfly does not have a stinger. However, the quote is 160 years old, there are likely many connotations with the phrase that have been lost over time.

Comment: @collapsar What would you expect from a text 160 years old, regarding the attribute of a _Stachel_? We meanwhile well know that horse flies don't have a sting. So what? The OP asks about that old text.

Comment: @collapsar But many [gadflies or horse-flies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horse-fly) can _bite_, and that bite hurts quite a bit. So people of earlier centuries probably misinterpreted which end of the fly brought the pain (and bloodloss). In German, we still speak of a "Mückenstich" (gnat bite), even though that insect uses it mouthparts as well.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If I knew what to expect, I'd have added it to my comment, or would have turned it into an answer. I just hinted at a (imho) strong piece of evidence against your suggestion that you appear quite convinced of.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck That would be an explanation. I'm still not convinced, however, as the gadfly would operate her stinger into a `raving odyssee`[`wüste Irrfahrt`] which makes no sense to me. Rather I would think of a particular braking contraption that is referred to here.

Comment: @collapsar Well, considering that the OP asks abourt a reasonable _"philosophical"_ text, I am trying to get most sense of it using the available alternatives besides naive attempts of translation.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Which certainly is the way to go, and in particular factoring in the notion of the 'absolute system' which the snippet discusses.

Comment: @collapsar I haven't read the whole text the excerpt is from, but I'd read "eine in wüste Irrfahrten hinausstachelnde Bremse" as an antipode to "Ruhekissen" (a cushion to rest on). According to the excerpt, the term "absolutes System" isn't to be used as a "Ruhekissen", but not as a "Bremse" either. It shouldn't sooth you (like the "Ruhekissen"), and it shouldn't agitate you (like the gadfly biting you here and there and everywhere and making you flail all over).

Comment: Der Witz dürfte sein, dass Pferde-Bremsen das Pferd bremsen, ne? Die Doppeldeutigkeit könnte immerhin gewollt sein. Außerdem sagt man durchaus immernoch, dass Bremsen beißen, habe ich aber nie selbst erfahren. Ich lese *herausstacheln* sowieso nicht unbedingt als *stechen*, sondern *stacheln* vielleicht wie in *anstacheln* (to poke, push, provoke) nur ohne *an-* eben.

Answer (score 1):

Here, in this context, *»Bremse«* does not mean *»break«* but [horse-fly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horse-fly). It is an insect that became rare in 21st century, but was very common when I was a child, and I guess horse-flies existed in an even bigger number 100 years before.

Those insects look like very big flies and are very annoying, because they suck blood from warm-blooded animals (including us humans), and when they bite you, you instantly feel pain similar to a wasp's sting. And because of this sting-like pain many people believed that horse-flies have stings (which is not the case) (I did believe this when I was a young child). So the words *»Bremse«* (*horse-fly*) and *»Stachel«* (*sting*) live in a semantic neighborhood, although horse-flies don't have stings. And from this semantic neighborhood inspired is the verb *»hinausstacheln«* (*to out-sting*), which I believe to be an invention of the author of your text. From the context I would conclude, that *»hinausstacheln«* means: *to fly away fast and in an erratic course.*

So, I would translate this nominal group this way:

> eine in wüste Irrfahrten hinausstachelnde Bremse
>   a horse-fly erratically bustling away in harsh wanderings

Comment: @vectory What have airbags (pillows for breaking) (Bremskissen), acupressure pillows (Stachelkissen) and sleeping pillows (Ruhekissen) to do with my answer about horse-flies?